# {{ theme.path }} and {{ theme.parent.path }} returning same value on child theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

I'm experimenting with Timber - so far I like it very much! I have run across one possible issue, though. I'm using the following in my index.php file:

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
Timber::render('index.twig', $context);
```

This is working fine. However, my theme is a child of TwentyFifteen, and the following lines in my view return the same values:

```
<p>{{ theme.path }}</p>
<p>{{ theme.parent.path }}</p>
```

They both return the child theme directory. Am I missing something? Twig is the only plugin I have active at the moment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about define('child_template_directory', dirname( get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url')) );

in a child theme functions.php.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain the problem thoroughly. Both values are the child theme directory, I need the parent theme directory. Completely forgot to mention that small tidbit...

Comment: Did you try get_template_directory_uri() / get_template_directory() / get_theme_root( $stylesheet_or_template ) / get_template() ?

Comment: get_template_directory() and get_template_directory_uri() both return the child theme directory path. get_theme_root() predictably returns the install theme directory, and get_template() returns the name of the child theme. I guess I can use get_theme_root() and hardcode in my values, I'm just wondering why {{ theme.parent.path }} is returning child theme information instead of parent theme info.